# What is wrong with NordVPN's iptables rules? Their staff can't fix issue

Tags: iptables, firewall, nordvpn

The NordVPN for Linux app has a port and subnet whitelisting feature. It is enabled with these commands (for my port and subnet):

```
nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.1.0/24
nordvpn whitelist add port 22
```

However, when that device is connected to the VPN, I cannot reach it by SSH from another device in my subnet. I wrote NordVPN support and they replied:

> Currently, we are having some issues with the NordVPN application for Linux regarding the port and subnet whitelisting.

They had no helpful advice to offer. I took a look at the iptables rules. They seem OK to me, but when I flushed all the rules (while connected to the VPN), I was then able to make the SSH connection to this device from my other local device. This indicates that the rules are not working correctly.

NordVPN's rules are:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun Apr 12 16:11:29 2020
*filter
:INPUT DROP [86:19526]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [103:7935]
-A INPUT -i nordlynx -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 89.87.71.71/32 -i lo -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -i lo -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 89.87.71.71/32 -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 89.87.71.71/32 -i nordlynx -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.5.0.0/16 -i nordlynx -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -i lo -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -i lo -p udp -m udp --dport 6568 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6568 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -i lo -p udp -m udp --dport 7070 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7070 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -i lo -p udp -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i lo -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 6568 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6568 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 7070 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7070 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 103.86.99.99/32 -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 103.86.96.96/32 -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 103.86.99.99/32 -o nordlynx -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 103.86.96.96/32 -o nordlynx -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o nordlynx -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 89.87.71.71/32 -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 89.87.71.71/32 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 89.87.71.71/32 -o nordlynx -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 10.5.0.0/16 -o nordlynx -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24 -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Apr 12 16:11:29 2020
```

I flushed them with:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X
```

My SSH connection worked as desired when the rules were flushed. (I restored NordVPN's rules by restarting it.) **What needs to change in the rules above so this device will accept incoming SSH connections (port 22) from the LAN?**

Info added in response to comment:

```
# ip -br address
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8
eth0             UP             192.168.1.3/24
nordlynx         UNKNOWN        10.5.0.2/16

# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
32765:  not from all fwmark 0xca6c lookup 51820
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 20100
10.5.0.0/16 dev nordlynx proto kernel scope link src 10.5.0.2
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.3 metric 100

ip route show table 51820
default dev nordlynx scope link
```

I'm using NordVPN's wireguard technology (nordlynx). But the issue exists when using openvpn technology instead of wireguard. I tested both ways.

Comment: @A.B I dumped the entire rules set. The flush commands are from a generic script I have.

Comment: @A.B added the additional info. How should I correct hte error you found?

Comment: While I think I more or less reproduced your setup, I couldn't reproduce your issue .I can just tell that the route entry `192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0` is dubious: it temporarily forces LAN traffic through the home router until it sends an ICMP redirect. But that's not causing trouble either.  I'm out of idea

Comment: @A.B yes, 89.87.71.71 is the remote VPN endpoint.

Comment: @A.B How should I fix `192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0`?

Comment: remove it: it's useless since there's already `192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.3 metric 100` . But I wouldn't know what added it. `ip route delete 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0`

Comment: If your home router is doing a kind of hairpinning where it SNATs everything from LAN to LAN with its own public IP (because of the dubious route above), that could be a cause. If you keep that route and you remove the iptables rules to have a working SSH, what source appears in the system when you log with SSH and type `who` (or `who --ips`) ?

Comment: @A.B No other device on my LAN has a route entry like `192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0`. When I log into any other device on my LAN and check `who` command, the IP address shown is the correct IP from the device I login from (e.g., 192.168.1.5). My home router is a Linux box running dnsmasq (based on IPFire - ipfire.org). Does that answer your question? (I cannot access the problematic device at this moment to run your test directly on it.)

Comment: Yes. Sorry really out of idea now

Comment: I also can't reproduce your error... I have a similar whitelisting rule (different internal subnet) and can successfully SSH in to the VPN machine, regardless of whether the VPN is turned on or not. Can you run `watch -n 2 -d iptables -nvL` to possibly see where the traffic is blocked? Or run `tcpdump port 22`?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, try whitelisting *`192.168.0.0/16`* instead of `192.168.1.0/24`. This worked for me on version 3.8.10.

David from NordVPN support had me try it just in case, and it worked. He said he couldn't explain why, because in theory `/24` should have worked, but since it's working for me now I can't complain too much.

Also, I was able to remove port 22 from my whitelist without it breaking SSH.